# Error detected while processing BufReadPost Auto commands for "*.html": E20: Mark not set

Tags: autocmd

I have what I thought was a pretty simple setup in my neovim init.vim file.  Basically all I wanted it to do was configure the tab settings when opening an HTML file.  My configuration is:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html, *.css
    \ set tabstop=2
    \ softtabstop=2
    \ shiftwidth=2
```

When I open an HTML file I get the following error message:

```
Error detected while processing BufReadPost Auto commands for "*.html":
E20: Mark not set
```

I don't understand why this is throwing an error.  I have a similar line in my config file for `*.py` yet I receive no errors when opening Python files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `|` to run multiple commands:

```
set tabstop=2 | softtabstop=2
```

It doesn't matter if you're using multiple lines, you still need to use the `|`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html, *.css
    \  set tabstop=2
    \| set softtabstop=2
    \| set shiftwidth=2
```

You can set multiple values with `set`, so the same can be expressed as:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html, *.css
    \ set tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
```

You probably want to use `setlocal`, rather than `set`. `set` will affect *all* buffers, so your autocommand will also change the settings for a `.js` buffer for example. `setlocal` will only affect the current buffer.

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html, *.css
    \ setlocal tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
```

Using the `Filetype` autocommand is probably better too. There may be other cases where the `html` or `css` syntax is loaded (for example my setting it manually):

```
au FileType html,css
    \ setlocal tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
```

Personally, I always want these three settings to have the same value, if you use `shiftwidth=0` it will use the value of the `tabstop` setting, and `softtabstop=-1` will make that use the `shiftwidth` setting, so then you can use:

```
set shiftwidth=0    " Use tabstop
set softtabstop=-1  " Use shiftwidth

au FileType html,css setlocal tabstop=2
```

Answer (score 4):

I have similar issue. The culprit is the **space between patterns**, like

`*.html,` and `*.css`

Removing **the space** should fix it. Good luck.

Reference > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416839/error-detected-while-processing-bufread-auto-commands-for-py

Comment: This was it. Thanks!